# How to calculate the difference between duplicates

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I calculate the difference of duplicate keys as shown below?

#### input

```
library(nycflights13)
head(flights, n=6) %>% select(origin, dep_time)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  origin dep_time
  <chr>     <int>
1 EWR         517
2 LGA         533
3 JFK         542
4 JFK         544
5 LGA         554
6 EWR         554
```

#### output

```
  origin dep_time
  <chr>     <int>
1 EWR         37
2 LGA         23
3 JFK         2
```

Comment: Just do `%>% group_by(origin) %>% summarise(dep_time = diff(dep_time))`

Comment: @akrun post this as an answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summarise` returns a dataset with one row for each group by column.  In the dataset 'flights' there are multiple rows for each 'origin'.  In that case, we could `summarise` as a `list` and then `unnest`

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
flights %>% 
   select(origin, dep_time) %>% 
   group_by(origin) %>%
   summarise(dep_time = list(diff(dep_time))) %>%
   unnest
```

Comment: What if I have additional columns along with dep_time. How can I extend the same function to the rest of the columns using "origin" as a group? Some thing like this `head(flights, n=6) %>% select(origin, dep_time, sched_dep_time, arr_time, sched_arr_time)`

Comment: @user1883491. If there are only a subset of columns that needs to be changed, use `summarise_at`

Answer (score 0):

You can use lag to calculate difference and then group-by by taking the last value for sequence of 2 origin

```
    Flight %>%
    arrange(Origin)%>%
    mutate(diff= Deptime - c(1, lag(Deptime)[-1]))%>%
    group_by(Origin)%>%
    summarise(last(diff))
```